# LibGdx with robovm: org.robovm.libimobiledevice.LibIMobileDeviceException: ApplicationVerificationFailed

Tags: android-studio, deployment, libgdx, ipa, robovm

at any moment Android Studio does not compile most of the iPhone 6 I own. But yesterday everything was ... today I find this error:

```
    [ERROR] Couldn't start application
org.robovm.libimobiledevice.LibIMobileDeviceException: ApplicationVerificationFailed
    at org.robovm.libimobiledevice.util.AppLauncher$1.error(AppLauncher.java:994)
    at org.robovm.libimobiledevice.Callbacks.callInstproxyCallback(Callbacks.java:57)
```

I downloaded the certificates from xCode preferences , but does not work the same.

The certificates in keychan are all updated and verified.

How can I fix ?

Comment: Same issue here, after the annual revoke and recreation of the development/production certificates. The new certificates have been installed on the development system. All provisioning profiles have been updated at apple's developer portal, downloaded in xcode and the RoboVM run configurations have been verified. But, no luck... Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

On [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/robovm/hlX8Lh2S-N4), Niklas Therning from the RoboVM team mentioned the following:

> I think this is a known bug when running against iOS 8 devices. The
>   work around is to first run a sample app from within Xcode to get the
>   developer image mounted on the device. Then you should be able to
>   launch RoboVM apps again until you reboot your device.

This fixed it after the annual certificate update.